# Need a push in learning pointers and void functions on C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sum, void

I just need a little push in the right direction. Firstly I'm having a bt trouble understanding pointers, to my understanding its kinda like a variable pointing to another variable you are referring to.  It doesnt seem right to me though :S

Secondly I am having trouble with the void functions, void functions can't return anything, now for my homework I am required to use a void function to do some process which will be used to in a print statement later.  Now the catch is I cannot print anything in the void function, I have to print it in the main function.  I am unsure on how the void function would put the data back to use in the print in the main since it won't return anything.  Here is an example of the function I am working with.

```
void fx1(int d[][5], int rows, int* colIndex, int* maxSum);
```

where:

- d is the array of data
- rows is the number of rows in d
- colIndex is the address for storing the column index of the column with the maximum sum
- maxSum is the address for storing the maximum column sum

purpose of that function is to get a set of numbers in an array Ie:

> 55, 8, 12, 6, -1
>
> -10, 4, 7, 5, -6
>
> -20, 0, 15, 4, -2

to calculate and find the column with the largest sum.

Now I know the logic behind its just that I am unsure howto return the final result back so it can be used or printing in the main, also the use of pointers for this case (and yes I have to use pointers, the entire point of this assignment is apparently to learn pointers).

Comment: You should try something, and then ask a specific question about a specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `sum` function like this:

```
void sum(int a, int b, int *result) {
    *result = a + b;
}
```

and use this in main:

```
int main() {
    int result;

    sum(1, 5, &result);

    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

hope this helps.